# Is, "please take this picture for me?" on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As a follow-on to my [variable-aperture question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21676/why-isnt-my-variable-aperture-photo-more-interesting) from a few days ago I'd like to ask for someone to take a picture like Imre suggested, because I don't have enough experience with flash to get a good result.  I thought I'd write up the type of result I'd like to see, and ask the community to take a few pictures for me.  Since it would probably take a bit of time and effort (and equipment and experience) to set up, I was going to offer a couple bounties to reward/encourage answers.

I don't recall seeing any questions like this.  If it goes well, it would open the door for questions like, "I took this picture with (extension tubes, my 50/1.8, a 200mm lens), can someone take the same picture with a more expensive (real macro lens, 50/1.4, super telephoto lens) and post the result so I can compare them?" which could be either really interesting, or really annoying.

Is this okay, or is it moving the site in a direction that people don't want to go?

Comment: If there was to be any valid place for such a request, it would probably not be the main forum. However, I don't think there is anything to say that using meta or, better yet, chat to make such a request is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be walking a really fine line of 'too localized' to me in terms of it being an entire question.  You're asking not merely for a macro shot with a lens (of which there are 2000000000 online) or a variable aperture shot, but for  *specific* image that is relevant to your question.

If you'd like to further a question by offering a bounty for an example shot, that sounds fine.  But this shouldn't be a question in and of itself.

Comment: I'd agree if "shoot this for me" werethe whole question, but adding a bounty for examples sounds okay.

Comment: @mattdm adding a bounty to an existing question, sure. But I thought he meant asking a question whose sole purpose to to ask for a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for a specific stock photo for some project is of course not appropriate.

But, I think setting a bounty *on an existing question* asking for an example picture is okay. This worked well for me at [Why are blown highlights particularly bad in digital photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13427/why-are-blown-highlights-particularly-bad-in-digital-photography). :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that worked for me in similar situation was to add a comment to the interesting [answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/21691/4390) to ask for example images. If that doesn't work, you can still offer a bounty for wider public, as @mattdm suggested.

Comment: Thanks for taking the initiative and making those pictures for me :)